# HDF5 files larger than expected using HDFql

Tags: hdf5, hdfql

Consider the following code, which simply dumps one million 2-Byte integers into a HDF5 file using HDFql:

```
std::string filepath = "/tmp/test.h5";
sprintf(script_, "CREATE TRUNCATE FILE %s", filepath.c_str());
HDFql::execute(script_);
sprintf(script_, "USE FILE %s", filepath.c_str());
HDFql::execute(script_);

HDFql::execute("CREATE CHUNKED DATASET data AS SMALLINT(UNLIMITED)");

const int data_size = 1000000;
std::vector<uint16_t> data(data_size);
HDFql::variableRegister(&data[0]);

for(int i=0; i<data_size; i++) {data.at(i)=i;}

sprintf(script_, "ALTER DIMENSION data TO +%d", num_data-1);
HDFql::execute(script_);

sprintf(script_, "INSERT INTO data(-%d:1:1:%d) VALUES FROM MEMORY 0", 0, num_data);
HDFql::execute(script_);
```

Since HDF5 is an efficient binary method of storing data, I'd expect this file size to be around 1E6*2 ~ 2MB big. Instead the file size is ~40MB! That's around 20 times larger than you'd expect. I found this after using HDFql to convert one binary format to HDF5, the resulting HDF5 files were *way* bigger than the original binary. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is not an issue that is peculiar to HDFql, but rather to the HDF5 data format itself. Since you are not explicitly defining a chunk size and because the dataset's dimension is unlimited, HDFql will automatically set this size to 1, which according to some info posted in http://hdf-forum.184993.n3.nabble.com/Questions-about-size-of-generated-Hdf5-files-td4029689.html will generate a lot of metadata that is stored in the HDF5 file (thus bloating its size).

Comment: So the size could be reduced by an upper bound on the size and defining a chunk size?

Comment: Yes, that could be.